# A Binomial Expansion (Sum of Coeffients)

Tags: binomial-theorem

If $(1+x+x^2)^n = a_{0}+a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2} +\cdots +a_{2n}x^{2n}$, then 
  find the value of $a_{0}+a_{3}+a_{6}+\cdots $.

Comment: Actually, that's not a binomial, but a [trinomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion), since it has three terms, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Set $x=1,\omega,\omega^2$ in the given identity where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity

Then add the three results

Use the fact $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$

To find $a_0+a_2+a_4+\cdots,$  set $x=1,-1$

Answer (score 1):

Like [To find the sum: $\frac {1}{n!} \sum \binom {n}{2+3r} x^{1+r}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183307/to-find-the-sum-frac-1n-sum-binom-n23r-x1r/3183321#3183321),

set $x=1,w,w^2$ where $w$ is one of the two complex cube(as we need to retain every third term) roots of unity.

let us find
 $$(a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{2n})+B(a_0+a_1w+a_2w^2+\cdots+a_{2n}w^{2n})+C(a_0+a_1w^2+a_2w^4+\cdots+a_{2n}w^{4n})$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a_0,a_1,a_2$

$$A+B+C=1$$

$$A+Bw+Cw^2=0$$

$$A+Bw^2+Cw=0$$

Solving the last two equations for $A,B$ in terms of $C,$ we get $A=B=C$

So, from the first equation $$A=B=C=\dfrac{A+B+C}3=?$$