# Summing Up Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$
\frac{\sum_{r=0}^{24}\binom{100}{4r}\binom{100}{4r+2}}{\sum_{r=1}^{25}\binom{200}{8r-6}}
$$

I tried this problem using Complex number approach and arrived at the solution. When I tried the numerical 'normally' by summing up the binomial coefficients using various properties I was encountering some difficulty in simplifying it.

Can anybody give an alternate approach to this problem?

Comment: Ramone, Sum of binomial coefficients is $2^n$, is this helpful?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183307/to-find-the-sum-frac-1n-sum-binom-n23r-x1r/3183321#3183321

Comment: I know that property but how to apply it here in the numerator ?

Comment: For numerator, $$(1+x)^{100}(1+1/x)^{100}$$

Comment: Can you please explain how ?